# Did I declare getpriorityvalues function in wrong way?

Tags: c++

I want to pass a priority value to main and other classes, but when I did it I get the wrong priority value. I don't know what part is wrong because it looks correct to me. When I run the code, it returns a random number for priority value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Process {

private:
    int ID; //I decleare variables
    int priority;
    int arrivaltime;
    int runtime;

public:
    Process(int id = -1, int p = 4, int arr = 0, int run = 0); //initiliazing
    int getpriorityvalues();
};
//contsructor
Process::Process(int id, int p, int arr, int run)
{
    int ID = id;
    int priority = p;
    int arrivaltime = arr;
    int runtime = run;
    cout << ID;
    cout << priority; //returning priority variable
}
//function that I want to use for variable passing
int Process::getpriorityvalues()
{
    cout << priority;
    cout << ID;
    cout << arrivaltime;
    cout << runtime;
    return priority;
}

#include <iostream>
#include "Process.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Process A; //object A
    int b = A.getpriorityvalues(); //result is not -4
    cout << b; //it is random number

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor you are not initializing the member variables, you are creating local variables which are destroyed when the constructor returns.

Use an initializer list on the constructor:

```cpp
Process::Process (int id,int p,int arr,int run)
  : ID{id},
    priority{p},
    arrivaltime{ar},
    runtime{run}
{
    cout<< ID;   
    cout<<priority; //returning priority variable  
}
```